# intent.action.PHONE_STATE broadcast receiver not working when app closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

i am trying to detect incoming calls by using this broadcast

```
   <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
    
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter  >
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

and this is java code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
//            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onMyCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }


//            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
//
//                    onMyCallStateChanged(context, state, phoneNumber);
//                }
//            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
```

the issue is when app get closed or removed from recent this broadcast not working. in android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), it is mentioned that this will work in the background

Comment: On what devices have you tested this?

Comment: How do you know that the `BroadcastReceiver` is not being called?

Comment: i am showing logs and toast in onMyCallStateChanged()
i have tested it on google pixel 2 android 11 and poco f2 pro with android 10
this only works when app is in the background or foreground but when app removed from recent its does not work strange!

Comment: @MateenChaudhry Did you find any solution? I have same issue as broadcast is not working when app is closed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this in the manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

if not, the broadcast receiver will silently fail.

Comment: of course, i have added these as i mentioned it working when the app is in the foreground